# How to create a menu tree using php?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am developing one e-commerce platform where admin can manage menu, category and sub-category. Now, I want display it in mega menu.

```
Menu1
    Category1.1
        SubCategory1
        SubCategory2
    Category1.2
        SubCategory
Menu2
    Category2.1
        SubCategory1
```

This is a possible structure with I came up.
I have 2 db tables - Menu, Category. In category, there is a column called `sub_category` where I am storing sub category values with `,` separator.

Now, after running below query -

```
$data = DB::select('SELECT m.id AS mId, m.name AS menu, 
m.meta_keywords AS menu_keywords, m.meta_description AS menu_description, 
c.id AS cId, c.name AS category, c.sub_category, c.meta_keywords AS
category_keywords, c.meta_description AS category_description 
FROM `menu` AS m LEFT JOIN `category` AS c ON c.menuId = m.id 
WHERE m.is_publish = 1 AND c.is_publish = 1');
```

I am getting result.[image: click]

Now, I want to build a tree where I can get a result something like this -

```
"id" => 1,
"name" => "Fashion"
"category" => [
    1 => [
        "cId" => 1,
        "category" => "Men"
        "sub_category" => "Shirt, T-shirt"
    ],
    2 => [
        "cId" => 2,
        "category" => "Women"
        "sub_category" => ""
    ],
]
```

Please help me out to find out solution. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your db structure and requirement, you can use below function -

```
public function menuTree($data){
        $menuId = $menu = $sub = $op = array();
        foreach($data as $d){
            if(in_array($d->mId, $menuId)){
                $sub['cId'] = $d->cId;
                $sub['category'] = $d->category;
                $sub['sub_category'] = $d->sub_category;
                $sub['category_keywords'] = $d->category_keywords;
                $sub['category_description'] = $d->category_description;
                $menu[$d->mId]['category'][] = $sub;
            } else {
                $menuId[] = $d->mId;
                $op['id'] = $d->mId;
                $op['menu'] = $d->menu;
                $op['menu_keywords'] = $d->menu_keywords;
                $op['menu_description'] = $d->menu_description;
                $menu[$d->mId] = $op;
                if($d->cId != NULL){
                    $sub['cId'] = $d->cId;
                    $sub['category'] = $d->category;
                    $sub['sub_category'] = $d->sub_category;
                    $sub['category_keywords'] = $d->category_keywords;
                    $sub['category_description'] = $d->category_description;
                    $menu[$d->mId]['category'][] = $sub;
                }
            }
        }
        return $menu;
    }
```

Still I believe there will be a better solution. Hope this works for you.